# How would I see which wordpress posts have a revision history without opening each one?

Tags: database, revisions

I have about 3000 CPT records with ACF data that were updated incorrectly by WP All Import. Is there a way to see a list of posts with revision histories? I have already exported the database, but can't see any indicators that show if a single post has a revision.

Edit: Is there a specific database for post revisions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Revisions documentation page](https://wordpress.org/support/article/revisions/#revision-storage-method):

> Revisions are stored in the posts table.
>
> Revisions are stored as children of their associated post (the same thing we do for attachments). They are given a `post_status` of `inherit`, a `post_type` of `revision`, and a `post_name` of `{parent ID}- revision(-#)` for regular revisions and `{parent ID}-autosave` for autosaves.

So you should be able to search the `wp_posts` table for posts where the `post_type` is `revision`, and then grab the `post_parent` ID to find the original post.

### Update

If you're looking for an SQL query, here's one I just tried that seemed to work:

```
SELECT ID, post_title
FROM wp_posts
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT post_parent
    FROM wp_posts
    WHERE post_type='revision'
);
```

...assuming your posts table has the default name `wp_posts`.